# How to count specific key values from a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, counting

I have a vendor data array listed as a tree structure and each vendor have a type.

These are types of vendor and its id:

- Agency = 1
- Branch Agency = 2
- Wholsaler = 3
- Smartshop = 4

Example: `['type']=>2` (here this vendor is a branch agency).

My question is: How can I get the count of Branch agencies are in this array, same count of wholesaler and smart shop?

Desired result:

[2 => 2, 3 => 2, 4 => 1]

Here is my dynamic generated array:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [type] => 2
            [name] => R-1 Agency
            [parent] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [type] => 3
                            [name] => R-1-W-1
                            [parent] => 2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [11] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 11
                                            [type] => 4
                                            [name] => mdf,lk
                                            [parent] => 3
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [id] => 38
            [type] => 2
            [name] => sndflk
            [parent] => 1
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [40] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 40
                            [type] => 3
                            [name] => new one
                            [parent] => 38
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I used this function :

```
function take_types($array){
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $types[] = $value['type'];
        if(!empty($value['children'])){
            $this->take_types($value['children']);
        }
    }
    return $types;
}
```

When I use the above function the output is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
)
```

I only get two values, I need to get the count of each vendor type.

Comment: What are you mean under the `specific key`? What you wanna get?

Comment: And _which_ specific key values are you trying to get? Where's your code?

Comment: Yes, you have the array, then? What specific key do you want? What have you tried?

Comment: this is prolly the vaguest question of the day, if there is such word. its like a movie, and then got cut off in the middle. please restate your question again and add your code

Comment: I need to get all value of named type key.                                                                

Example :
Array
(   [alltypes]=>Array
    (
 [0]=>2
        [1]=>3
        [2]=>4
        [3]=>2
        [4]=>3
    )
   
)

Comment: When providing sample data for volunteers,  use `var_export()`.  I often answer from my phone, reformatting your data just to start testing makes your question unattractive for me to answer.

Answer (score 0):

There will be many techniques to recursively process your tree data.  I'll offer a native function style and a custom recursive style.

`array_walk_recursive()` visits all of the "leaf nodes", so you only need to check the key and push the value into a variable which can be accessed outside of that function's scope -- this is why "modifying by reference" is vital.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CK10T))

```
// I removed the chunky $tree declaration from my post, see the demo
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive(
    $tree,
    function($v, $k) use (&$result) {
        if ($k === 'type') {
            $result[] = $v;
        }
    }
);
var_export(array_count_values($result));
```

Or

```
function recursiveTypeCount($array, $output = []) {
    foreach($array as $item) {
        if (!isset($output[$item['type']])) {
            $output[$item['type']] = 1;
        } else {
            ++$output[$item['type']];
        }
        if ($item['children']) {
            $output = recursiveTypeCount($item['children'], $output);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

var_export(recursiveTypeCount($tree));
```

Both will display:

```
array (
  2 => 2,
  3 => 2,
  4 => 1,
)
```

Comment: @Rauf I see that you have not yet accepted any answers on Stack Overflow, do you know how it works?  Please read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/352329